# Google drive API throwing strange errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I am trying to move files using service account. Following is my code.

```
async function moveAndRenameFile(drive: drive_v3.Drive, fileId: string, addParents: string, name: string) {
  const file = await drive.files.get({
    fileId,
    fields: "parents",
  });

  await drive.files.update({
    fileId,
    addParents,
    removeParents: file.data.parents?.join(","),
    requestBody: {
      name,
    },
  });
}
```

This is also the recommended way as in google docs - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/folder

It was working fine. However, today I see that it throws following erros.

```
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/drive/v3/files/?addParents=1gRegyMFzluU46m0CdE917EGXIEzZSKIp</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>     

    at Gaxios._request (C:\Users\G\Documents\web\isk\rsp-media\node_modules\.pnpm\gaxios@5.1.3\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:140:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async JWT.requestAsync (C:\Users\G\Documents\web\isk\rsp-media\node_modules\.pnpm\google-auth-library@8.9.0\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:382:18)
    at async moveAndRenameFile (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/admin/upload.ts:132:5)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/admin/upload.ts:79:9) {
  digest: undefined
}
```

Comment: sounds like the file doesn't exist or the service account doesn't have access.